# Javacard form factors

Tags: smartcard, javacard

I'm totally new in the Smartcard world, and would really appreciate some clarifications regarding Javacard form factors and interfaces, as I've found it very hard to research the different options.

Ideally I would like to find a contactless Javacard 2 (or 3) chip + antenna that is not encased in plastic, because I want to put it inside another product. I want it to be as small as possible, and therefore just contactless, not dual interface.

However all the Javacards I've found that's sold by manufacturers, seem to only have the "business card" form factor. Does anyone know if this is available at all or if not, or at least theoretically possible to produce? Does the Javacard version make any difference in feasibility of this form factor (My applet only requires Javacard 2+)?

If anyone knows what a reasonable bulk price per chip with such a form factor would be, that would also be very interesting to hear.

Thank you!

Comment: **Contactless only** will never be the smallest possible, since the antenna (if considered in total size) needs a certain area to be effective, especially if it also has to provide the power to the chip. While this may not need to be as large as ID-1 (see ISO 7810) , you would get smaller with a pure contact-based chip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that you find these chips only in smart cards is that that is the best method of developing on them without hassle. There are also form factors for use in e.g. key fobs, which is probably what you're after. That means smaller antenna space and less chance of a good response. These chips and antenna's are tricky to get right so that all distances and orientations work well.

Paper smart cards are commonly not smart cards but throw away memory cards like MiFare or MiFare ultra-light. Usually smart cards come in credit card form, like -uh- those in credit cards. And then they are in plastic (PVC) or polycarbonate for the higher end cards. Demo cards are usually plastic though. Manufacturers aren't shy of not putting any chips or antenna's in there at all when it comes to demo cards (they might be showing off their printing capabilities instead).

The *classic* Java cards can be in any form factor. However, the more memory the larger the die may be. That can be an issue with some *packaging*, the small container that the IC is put in and to which the antenna's are connected. Although Java Card 3 is somewhat of a jump in functionality, most cards capable of version 2 would also be OK to run version 3 of Java Card.

The failed web-based "connected" Java Card requires a lot of memory and *if* you can find it, it will probably be limited to specific form factors. Java Card 3.1 seems to be another jump in functionality for the common "classic" platform and I would expect for high end smart cards to lead the way.

---

Generally we don't talk prices here. If you are interested in bulk pricing for specific form factors then you need to contact the resellers, not us. But I would first try and read into it. There are some great general purpose books out there on smart cards. That way you'd at least know a bit what you're talking about when contacting such vendor, and in that case you're more likely to be taken seriously.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer Maarten.